# ASP.NET User Control not propagating CssClass on rendering

Tags: asp.net, css, user-controls

I have a user control that I am programmatically setting the CssClass attribute in the code behind.

I am using IE 9 and I can see the className property is appropriately filled when I use Script tab in the F12 tools.  However it is not showing up in the HTML tab of F12.  Is there a reason for this or possibly something I am missing during the ASP.NET lifecycle.

I understand this isn't a lot to go and there might not be enough information to solve this issue.  I have never encountered an issue where I can see something in javascript watch value, but that it does not propagate to the HTML tab.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the control being styled as you wanted? And is it showing when you just View Source from within the browser?

Comment: No it is not.  That's what I am trying to figure out.  If I add the class through the F12 tools to the HTML element, then it does style appropriately.

Comment: You're setting the CssClass in code behind for a reason - is the logic all handled server side, or does the (any) javascript dictate what the cssclass will be?

Comment: The javascript is simply to toggle the class, but running through all of the javascript it is not getting toggled.  Unless F12 is telling me erroneous data.

Comment: I think this is about working process of asp.net. Asp.net server side control runs via a javascript code. So you can't see it in html tab. It's about postback issue: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/ajax_callback.htm

Comment: I can see the control in the HTML tab just fine, it just doesn't have the attribute for the class.